# Efficient way to reuse the same call to the same sql table

Tags: php, mysql

So I search for this title hoping someone would have already answered it however, I came across similar topics on other languages but not PHP so maybe this will help others.

I am constantly using this following script to call on the database but how can I create it so that I can make it just once at the top of the class for example and use it in every method on the class page that needs it. Example: An single page may not have all of the data it needs from the same table but if the table contains 50% of the data or more for that page, how can I modify this so that I can just say it once and let the rest of the following scripts display the data it extracted in the first place by calling it all just once?

Here's what I have now.

```
<?php
    if($res = $dbConn->query("SELECT Column FROM Table")){
        while($d = $res->fetch_assoc()){
            printf("Enter HTML here with proper %s", $d['Column']);
        }
    }
?>
```

I want to call on this without the `printf(" ");` collect and store the data so that I can then call the results while printing or echoing the results with the HTML in other methods. What os the most efficient way? I don't want to make the same call over and over and over... well, you get the point.

Should I use fetch_array or can I still do it with fetch_assoc?

Comment: Can you not just put the query in a function which returns the results? Then you can just call the function wherever you want, and do whatever you want with the returned results. Edit: Or if you are talking about actually being efficient in the query itself, have a look at caching the query

Comment: What's the most efficient way to return the result in this example? Use same code but instead printf, use return? or do you have a more eloquent way to write this?

Answer (score 0):

not very sure if it's the answer you want.
you can use `include/include_once/require/require_once` at the top of the page you want to use the function

for example:

```
general_function.php:
-----
function generate_form( $dbConn, $sql ) {
    if($res = $dbConn->query("SELECT Column FROM Table")) {
        while($d = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            printf("Enter HTML here with proper %s", $d['Column']);
        }
    }
}
```

and for those pages you want to use the function, just put

```
include "$PATH/general_function.php";
```

and call generate_form

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class QueryStorage {
    public static $dbConn = null;
    public static $results = [];

    public static function setConnection($dbConn) {
      self::$dbConn = $dbConn;
    }

    public static function query($query, $cache = true) {
      $result = (array_key_exists($query, self::$results))? 
                self::$results[$query] : self::$dbConn->query($query);
      if($cache) {
        self::$results[$query] = $result;
      }

      return $result;
    }

    public static function delete($query) {
      unset(self::$results[$query]);
    }

    public function clean() {
      self::$results = [];
    }
}
```

usage:

at top somewhere pass connection to class:

```
QueryStorage::setConnection($dbConn);
```

query and store it:

```
$result = QueryStorage::query("SELECT Column FROM Table", true);

if($result){
  while($d = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    printf("Enter HTML here with proper %s", $d['Column']);
  }
}
```

reuse it everywhere:

```
$result = QueryStorage::query("SELECT Column FROM Table", true); // it will return same result without querying db second time
```

> **Remember:** it's runtime cache and will not store result for second script run. for this purposes You can modify current class to make it
>   work with memcache, redis, apc and etc.

Comment: I like this version, the query and store portion is only done once at the top of the page? or is it used elsewhere?

Comment: You include class at top, then at top pass connection link. Just do $result = QueryStorage::query("SELECT Column FROM Table"); where You need it. It will seamlessly store query result in classes results array.

Comment: Sounds great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then the trick is to make an associative array and access with its 'key' down the code.

```
     $dataArray = array();
    // Add extra column in select query for maintaining uniqness. 'id' or it can be any unique value like username.

    if($res = $dbConn->query("SELECT Column,id FROM Table")){
        while($d = $res->fetch_assoc()){
            $dataArray[$d['id']] = $d['Column'];
        }
    }

    //you have value in the array use like this:
    echo $dataArray['requireValueId'];
    //or , use 'for-loop' if you want to echo all the values
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a function which takes in the query as a parameter and returns the result.

Like this:

```
public function generate_query($sql) {
    if($res = $dbConn->query($sql)){
        while($d = $res->fetch_assoc()){
            printf("Enter HTML here with proper %s", $d['Column']);
        }
    }
}
```